# Getting XHTML embedded in XML

Tags: java, dom, xml-parsing, xhtml

I'm trying to get XHTML embedded in an XML node like this:

```
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    ...
    <content type="xhtml">
        <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <p>some text</p>
        </div>
    </content>  
    ...
</entry>
```

I expect to get:

```
<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <p>some text</p>
</div>
```

But all I get is:

```
some text
```

And this is my code so far:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
DocumentBuilder db = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = db.parse(methodeArticleXml);

System.out.println(doc.getElementsByTagName("content").item(0).getTextContent());
```

The parser is treating the content as XML instead XHTML or plain text, is there a way around this?

I can't change the format of the document, so using CDATA is not an option.

Comment: You are calling `getTextContent()` which will get only the plain text content.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hack with a regex

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<content[^>]*>(.*?)</content>", Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(xml);
while (matcher.find()) {
    String content = matcher.group(1);
    doStuff(content);
}
```